# How to use SDR equipment and Gnuraio record `time domain` data?

Tags: software-defined-radio, gnuradio, frequency

From [answer](https://ham.stackexchange.com/a/20693/4076),

> A comment has pointed out that one could think of the saved data as in
> the time domain under some circumstances because it is literally
> series of 32-bit values written as fast as possible in time order. I
> think this is a conceptual mistake

As `gnuradio` `sink` data byte by byte,not second by second,Can I suppose `time scale` of data is uniform distribution? If not,can I process data with `fft(data)`?

Comment: hi! Your link to an answer is sadly broken! Could you fix it? I think the context of the answer might really help here!

Comment: Ah found it, fixed it. The literal next sentence after the sentence you've copied seems to answer your question.

Comment: In my Answer I link to the GNU Radio tutorial that shows how you can simulate a frequency sink using an FFT and other blocks, which shows how this works. Of course, the FFT block also works in reverse, which you could experiment with.

Comment: @jdv,FFT block in gnuradio is multiply with window.Is there pure FFT block in gnuradio?

Comment: @kittygirl not sure. The window size is optional, I recall.

Answer (score 2):

You've omitted the next sentence which answers your question:

> It only really holds for data that you know is sensible values vs. time.

And a time-domain sampled signal is exactly that. As, by the way, two sentences later also already tell you:

> So, yes. If you are capturing Complex data, it will be a series of real and imaginary parts in order that could be easily expressed as being in the time domain.

also:

> can I process data with fft(data)

we already established you can, in other questions of yours. You do need to read back the data in its original format. Which complex numbers composed of interleaved 32 bit floats in your machine-native format.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!Ask one more thing,what cause `sink data` uniform distribution in time domain?the LO?

Comment: the fact that you're sampling at a sampling rate. The LO has absolutely nothing to do with it. I think it would be a very good idea if you took a big step back und made a drawing of your system, which involves everything from the receive antenna to the file sink, and clearly label what kind of signal (band pass or low pass and continuous-time or discrete time) you have at each point.

Comment: I'm just going to give this answer a down-vote because I think it's poorly written.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how it's poorly written? (this question goes out both to you, @Jack0220 and to the person who upvoted that comment within 5 minutes of it being posted). I'm willing to improve it! I don't care about reputation points much, I care about the quality of my answers.

Comment: I suppose someone could address the specific question about whether the data time scale is a uniform distribution in the file. My understanding is that it isn't (but that doesn't matter), which is why I'm making the conceptual distinction in the related Answer. But I am cheerfully willing to be proven wrong.

Comment: @JohnVE3WNA I can't know that, as I explain in the next sentence: Conditionally to the signal being sampled like that, "So, yes."

Comment: (we might have a misunderstanding on "as fast as possible" in the comment you cite, which I guess is mine: it's really just "in time order"; the "as fast as possible" describes the process of writing to the file, not anything "happening" DSP-wise)

Comment: I meant "Can I suppose time scale of data is uniform distribution?" It seems to me that (as you say) the whole point of the sample rate is how fast we can stream the data to the file, but I don't think there is any promise of a range of this "time domain" data being put in the file uniformly across time.

Comment: (But I'm not sure what anyone wants from any of these Q&A.)

Comment: you're absolutely right. The properties we ascribe to the signal are our business, GNU Radio really only sees a sequence of numbers. Actually, not even that. It sees items of a given byte length. For all that GNU Radio cares, it could be processing text or vector images.

Comment: Hey Jack, I don't think that's a good reason for downvoting an answer!

Comment: @Jack0220 "I don't like it" isn't a reasonable reason to downvote.

Comment: Man, do people get bent out of shape over Gnu Radio. It's a tool, not a perfect research model. Each module has well-defined inputs and outputs, and well-defined behaviours. The file sink eats data as fast as possible, and lays that down into a well-defined file format with literally no other promises. If you feed it a stream of complex 32's or floats, that's what it writes. No other guarantees. The intelligence -- the domain -- is a human construct that we use so we can have a conversation about some data _after we've done something with it_.

Comment: That is very well said, @JohnVE3WNA!